# How to write a playlist from an IceCast stream in C#

Tags: c#, streaming, stream, icecast

i want to monitor an icecast stream and write all file information (the actually played mp3) i can get to a local playlist for later processing.

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to extract the stream metadata, the following code project article describes ripping a SHOUTcast stream (same thing as icecast) and extracting the song data i.e. stream metadata:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/SHOUTcastRipper.aspx